# php array ouput "null" values (values extracted from json file)

Tags: php, json

I've modify this code to get data from a json file instead of xml file (my old code)

```
<?php 
$tracking_id = 'MyID'; //This is used to track the user doing the offer. can be email, clickid, subid.. etc 
$userip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //We need to get the users ip, so the rss feed can display the correct offers for their country. 
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; //lets collect their user agent to pass along. 
$max_offers = 5; //max number of offers to display. 


$str = file_get_contents('https://www.cpalead.com/dashboard/reports/campaign_json_load_offers.php?id=296213&geoip='.$userip.'&ua='.urlencode($user_agent).'&subid='.urlencode($tracking_id));
$json = json_decode($str, true);
$opOffer = array();
$offer_cnt = 0; 
foreach($json['offers'] as  $offeritem)
{
$opOffer[$offer_cnt] = array("title" => array($offeritem->title), "link" => array($offeritem->link)); 
$offer_cnt++; 
};
if (0 == count($opOffer)): 
echo 'Sorry there are no offers available for your region at this time.'; 
else: 
echo json_encode($opOffer); 
endif; 


?>
```

and it's output like this:

```
[{"title":[null],"link":[null]},{"title":[null],"link":[null]},{"title":[null],"link":[null]},{"title":[null],"link":[null]},{"title":[null],"link":[null]},{"title":[null],"link":[null]},{"title":[null],"link":[null]},{"title":[null],"link":[null]},{"title":[null],"link":[null]},{"title":[null],"link":[null]},{"title":[null],"link":[null]}]
```

it should be like this:

```
[{"title":[{"What is Your Favorite Time for McDonald's?"}],"link":[{"https:\/\/filetrkr.com\/show.php?l=0&u=31802&id=5882&tracking_id=MyId"}]}]
```

Link to see json output: https://www.cpalead.com/dashboard/reports/campaign_json_load_offers.php?id=296213

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the line:

```
$opOffer[$offer_cnt] = array("title" => array($offeritem->title), "link" => array($offeritem->link));
```

Shouldn't it be either:

```
$opOffer[$offer_cnt] = array("title" => $offeritem->title, "link" => $offeritem->link);
```

or:

```
$opOffer[$offer_cnt] = array("title" => $offeritem['title'], "link" => $offeritem['link']);
```

Also, just after the line:

```
$json = json_decode($str, true);
```

Add this line and post the results:

```
echo "<p>JSON: <pre>".print_r($json,true)."</pre></p>";
```

That last bit to verify you are receiving the JSON you think you should be getting.

Comment: now the output is in the exact format using this:
    $opOffer[$offer_cnt] = array("title" => $offeritem['title'], "link" => $offeritem['link']);

just need to be only 5 offers ($max_offers = 5;) not all offers

Comment: So inside the foreach, test for max records and break out of the loop: if(cnt > 5) { break; }

Comment: Yes it worked, but output showup like this:

[{},{},{}]

It should be like this:
[{[{}],[{}],[{}]}]

Answer (score 0):

I just changed:

```
$opOffer[$offer_cnt] = array("title" => array($offeritem->title), "link" => array($offeritem->link));
```

to:

```
$opOffer[$offer_cnt] = array("title" => array($offeritem["title"]), "link" => array($offeritem["link"]));
```

And now give me what you want on the JSON:

```
[{"title":["Amplificador de Bater\u00eda"],"link":["http:\/\/gtrcking.com\/offer.php?id=744798&pub=296213&subid=MyID"]},{"title":["\u0645\u0628\u0627\u0631\u0627\u0629 \u0645\u0630\u0647\u0644\u0629!"],"link":["http:\/\/gtrcking.com\/offer.php?id=550635&pub=296213&subid=MyID"]},....
```

Answer (score 0):

heres what you want. give that a go.

```
foreach($json['offers'] as  $offeritem)
{
$opOffer[$offer_cnt] = array("title" => array($offeritem['title']), "link" => array($offeritem['link'])); 
$offer_cnt++;
if ($offer_cnt == $max_offers) break;
};
```